# How to make the City field a dropdown selection depending on the county selected?

Tags: civicrm-home

Basically what it says in the title. Currently, the City field in the Address is a free text field. Is it possible to make it dropdown or even auto-complete from a set of predefined cities?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by 'is it possible'? My answer would be: yes it is possible but not without coding. You would have to make a small extension that would enable this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would do this with civix I imagine. Which files would I need to alter and how? Can you recommend a resource which would help me to achieve this?

Comment: If you are still there: the Developer Guide would help, and specifically the sections on adding jQuery to templates: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/customizing/